# Microsoft.Win32.Registry Fields Null in UnitTest Project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

My Setup:

- Windows 7 Professional x64
- Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop
- .Net Framework v4.5
- Using C#

I noticed that all static properties (LocalMachine, CurrentUser, etc) for `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` are `null` at runtime in a unit test project.  Why is this so?

I created a new project using the *Unit Test Project* template.  The code is as follows:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine;
        }
    }
}
```

After building the project, I set a breakpoint on the `RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine;` line, and I ran the test using the debugger (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).

When the breakpoint was hit, I brought up the *Immediate Window*, typed `Registry` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  I ended up with the following output:

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry
    base: object
    ClassesRoot: null
    CurrentConfig: null
    CurrentUser: null
    DynData: null
    LocalMachine: null
    PerformanceData: null
    Users: null
```

**Note:** I have read [an article](http://www.rhyous.com/2011/11/04/unit-testing-code-that-touches-the-system/), which states that unit tests should not touch the system.  The author provides information on wrapping and mocking code that accesses the registry, and I agree with the author's reasoning.  Ultimately, this is probably what I will do.

I am still interested in the *technical* reason(s) that those properties are null.

Cheers.

---

**Update [2014-10-12]**
I am running Visual Studio under an administrator account (I right-click and run as administrator).

As a test, I added a console project to the same solution, and added the same code to the `Main` method. I set a breakpoint, inspected `Microsoft.Win32.Registry`, and the aforementioned Registry properties are not null.

Comment: Are you running *Visual Studio under a Administrator account*?

Comment: Yes, I am running under an administrator account.  I have updated my post to include this information.